# UITextView object is not being recognized in new controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, viewcontroller

I'm kind of new to Swift programming, so this question might look silly!

I have a new viewController named InfoViewController and I have connected it to the visual view controller in main.storyboard as the figure below:

As you can see, the view controller in main.storyboard is connected to `InfoViewController.swift`
[image: screenshot]

However, when I insert the UITextView into the InfoViewController.swift, it does not recognize it as the following pic.

[image: link of image]

What is the problem, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the outlet property on the from outside method. In viewDidLoad method you can easily access the `myText` outLet.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myText.text = "something new"
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. So swift is function-based. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just throw code inside the view... swift is function based... so you might want to create a function to call myText Label inside...

create this function on your class:

```
function changeMyLabelText(){
  self.myLabel.setText("New Text")
}
```

And call it inside viewDidLoad method with

```
self.changeMyLabelText()
```